# different render layout in controller not load properly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, controller

in my controller I have 2 layout, but when after redirect the layout not change? i won't just action :new_line_items using layout "application" and another using layout "front_layout"

my controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController      
  layout :compute_layout

  before_filter :collect_menu, :only => [:show_item, :location, :order_items, :new_line_items]

  def index
    @stores = Store.all
    if !params[:store_id].blank?
      @store = Store.find(params[:store_id])
      menu_left_all(params[:store_id]) if !@store.blank?
    end
  end

  def show_item
    @store = Store.find(params[:store_id])
    item_childs(params[:id])
  end

  def location
    @store = Store.find(params[:store_id])
  end

  def new_line_items

  end

  def create_line_items    
    @store = Store.find(params[:store_id])
    item = Item.find(params[:id])        
    line_items = item.line_items.build(quantity: params[:quantity])

    respond_to do |format|
      if line_items.save
        format.html { redirect_to stores_url, notice: 'Line Items was successfully created.' }
      end
    end
  end

  def compute_layout
    if request.url.include?("new_line_items")
      action_name = "application"
    else
      action_name = "front_layout" 
    end  
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of your compute_layout method and change `layout :compute_layout' to`layout 'front_layout`. This will set default layout for all the actions.

To change layout for single action do:

```
def new_line_items
  render layout: 'application'
end
```

Another solution:

If you think the layouts might change in the future, you should keep your `compute_layout` method, but change it:

```
def compute_layout
  if action_name == "new_line_items"
    "application"
  else
    "front_layout" 
  end  
end
```